# regular expression to match binary words

Tags: regex

I am in dire need of a such regular expression where my alphabet is made up of 0s and 1s.

Now I need a language that accepts all words as long as it has three 0s.

IE:

000
10001
0001
1000
10000101

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to capture every word(delimited by spaces) that contains 3 or more 0s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three *consecutive* zero chars:

```
\b[01]*0{3}[01]*\b
```

**Note**
It is not entirely clear whether this is what OP wants.

**Edit**
Apparently it was :)

Answer (score 3):

```
\b(1*0){3}
```

will also match if the three zeros are not consecutive.

This only matches as much as required (i.e. up until the third zero). If you want it to match the entire number, use

```
\b(1*0){3}[01]*\b
```

Comment: +1 Elegant and nice thought to only match "as much as required".

Answer (score 0):

You mean a number that can be divided by 3 zeros, such as 3, 6, 9? or 3 more or zeros?

Comment: Divide by zero? Huh? Oh!... :)

Comment: If a number can be divided by two zeros, can you divide that number by three zeros?

Comment: right, the statement should've been written as"a number of zeros that can be divided by 3" :)